# Can somebody explain what this function does and how it works?

Tags: python

One of the review questions for my midterm is to understand what this function does and I cannot read it because I don't understand where the parameters come from and how it works. Can somebody with programming experience help?

```
def enigma(numList, n, pos):
    length = len(numList)
    if pos == length:
        print('Error')
        return

    newList = []
    for i in range(pos):
        newList = newList + [numList[i]]

    newList = newList + [n]

    tailLength = length - pos
    counter = tailLength
    while counter < length:
        newList = newList + [numList[counter]]
        counter = counter + 1

    return newList
```

Comment: Work through it step by step. Use paper, if you need, to keep track of the variables. The parameters will be a list of numbers `numList`, a number (`n`) and an integer (`pos`). Just try something like `enigma([1,2,3], 4, 2)` and trace through it.

Answer (score 0):

Many times trying some test data reveals the functionality quickly:

```
>>> enigma('abcdefghijklm', 'X', 0)
['X']
>>> enigma('abcdefghijklm', 'X', 1)
['a', 'X', 'm']
>>> enigma('abcdefghijklm', 'X', 2)
['a', 'b', 'X', 'l', 'm']
>>> enigma('abcdefghijklm', 'X', 3)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'X', 'k', 'l', 'm']
>>> enigma('abcdefghijklm', 'X', 4)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'X', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']
>>> enigma('abcdefghijklm', 'X', 12)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'X', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']
>>> enigma('abcdefghijklm', 'X', 13)
Error
```

The code starts with an empty `new_list` and builds it up in three sections

- The repeating the first `pos` number of elements
- Adding the `n` element
- Repeating the trailing `pos` number of elements

As `pos` becomes larger than the midpoint, the beginning and trailing elements sections cross over to repeat some items.